# com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up

Tags: mongodb, search, elasticsearch

My search is not working now. I guess because my index was not configured for replica set:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "mongodb", 
  "mongodb": { 
    "db": "mongo", 
    "host": "local", 
    "port": "40000", 
    "collection": "users"
  }, 
  "index": { 
    "name": "api", 
    "type": "users" 
  }
}'`
```

Is there anyway to declare a replica set properly so that elasticsearch can find the master, the way PHP driver does:

```
$m = new Mongo(
  "mongodb://localhost:40000,localhost:41000", 
  array("replicaSet" => true)
);
```

so that elasticsearch can automatically fail over to another member.

Comment: What is the ElasticSearch River you are using? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Hi @J-16,
I use this: https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb.

Comment: I found out that I can solve this problem by create 2 instance of river driver to pull data from both members of replica set.

Comment: This issue is totally solved by the latest driver from https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this simply by updating to the latest version of the client driver.

The previous (minor) version had trouble connecting to the latest mongo server.